# The final URL isn't reachable for NextJS / Vercel site

Tags: next.js, adsense, vercel

I'm trying to run our first Google Ads campaign. Currently getting an error from Google Ads saying "The final URL isn't reachable". I've tried with and without the `www` and with our without the trailing `/`.

We are using Vercel and Next.JS. The domain is setup fully utilizing Vercel to manage the DNS. This is exactly the same as https://www.michaelpierce.dev my portfolio site, and when I enter that, Google Ads has no problems accessing.

I saw another form post on the Google [forums](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/89716936/the-final-url-isn-t-reachable-in-google-ads?hl=en) and it said to check the redirects.

Status Code,Scheme,Host,Path

```
308,http://,www.greetbox.co,
200,https://,www.greetbox.co,/
```

Status Code,Scheme,Host,Path

```
308,http://,www.michaelpierce.dev,
307,https://,www.michaelpierce.dev,
200,https://,michaelpierce.dev,/
```

Interesting though, the lack of 307 for GreetBox.co.

I've also checked Google Search Console, and the index page is read properly.

[Google Search Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nDBC.jpg)

Any recommendations on how to solve this issue?

Thank you!